# Zipping Files -- apostrophe in path name

Tags: bash, path, zip, escaping

I'm unable to zip any file that has an apostrophe in a folder name.  e.g.

`zip -rmT "./I've Been Everywhere (Today)/PDFs.zip" "./PDFDirectory"`

or

`zip -rmT ./I\'ve\ Been\ Everywhere\ \(Today\)/PDFs.zip ./PDFDirectory`

I've tried all manner of quoting, escaping, and using variables instead of typing the strings but still get

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

test of I've Been Everywhere (Today)/PDFs.zip FAILED
```

This is happening both on the command line and in bash script. Removing apostrophes/single quotes from the path clears the error.  Is Zip unable to handle apostrophes in path names or am I missing something?

*UPDATE 09/22/21 1443 EDT*

Marco is correct, it is the -T (--test) that is causing the error.  Since I need that test, I'm currently working around the issue by cd into the folder and cd back after zipping is complete (YUCK!).

Comment: I think it's the `-T` (`--test`) option that is causing the error, it also says: `zip error: Zip file invalid, could not spawn unzip, or wrong unzip (original files unmodified)
free(): double free detected in tcache 2`

Comment: Steven, if my answer was helpful, please mark it as accepted. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the `-T` (`--test`) option doesn't handle single quotes `'` in
filepaths very well. if you run your command without it, it should work fine,
but you'll lose the integrity check. a better workaround would be to create the
zip file in the current directory and only later move it into
`I've Been Everywhere (Today)` directory, e.g.:

```
$ zip -rmT PDFs.zip PDFDirectory && mv PDFs.zip "I've Been Everywhere (Today)"
  adding: PDFDirectory/ (stored 0%)
  adding: PDFDirectory/bar.pdf (stored 0%)
  adding: PDFDirectory/baz.pdf (stored 0%)
  adding: PDFDirectory/foo.pdf (stored 0%)
test of PDFs.zip OK
$ ls I\'ve\ Been\ Everywhere\ \(Today\)/
PDFs.zip
$
```

(see at the end for another workaround using `-b` option)

---

just for fun I tried to look at the [`zip` program source code](https://sourceforge.net/projects/infozip/files/Zip%203.x%20%28latest%29/3.0/zip30.tar.gz/download) to (try to)
understand what is going on ([here a github mirror](https://github.com/LuaDist/zip)).

as already said, the problem only occurs (I think) with the `-T` option which
does integrity check of the zip file. from `man zip`:

> **-T**
> **--test**
>
> Test  the  integrity of the new zip file. If the check fails, the old zip file
> is unchanged and (with the -m option) no input files are removed.
>
> **-TT cmd**
> **--unzip-command cmd**
>
> Use command cmd instead of 'unzip -tqq' to test an archive when the -T  option
> is  used.  On Unix, to use a copy of unzip in the current directory instead of
> the standard system unzip, could use:
>
> ```
> zip archive file1 file2 -T -TT "./unzip -tqq"
> ```
>
> In cmd, {} is replaced by the name of the  temporary  archive,  otherwise  the
> name of the archive is appended to the end of the command.  The return code is
> checked for success (0 on Unix).

when using the `-T` option, `zip` runs `unzip -tqq` on the zip file. I tracked down
the piece of code that actually does this in `zip.c`, the function is:

```
local void check_zipfile(zipname, zippath)
  char *zipname;
  char *zippath;
  /* Invoke unzip -t on the given zip file */
```

it's long and really "#ifdef-heavy", I assume you are on a unix-like system, I'll report
only the relevant parts:

```
    if ((cmd = malloc(20 + strlen(zipname))) == NULL) {
      ziperr(ZE_MEM, "building command string for testing archive");
    }

    strcpy(cmd, "unzip -t ");
...
    if (!verbose) strcat(cmd, "-qq ");
    if (check_unzip_version("unzip") == 0)
      ZIPERR(ZE_TEST, zipfile);

# ifdef UNIX
    strcat(cmd, "'");    /* accept space or $ in name */
    strcat(cmd, zipname);
    strcat(cmd, "'");
...
  }

  result = system(cmd);
...
  free(cmd);
  cmd = NULL;
  if (result) {
...
    fprintf(mesg, "test of %s FAILED\n", zipfile);
    ziperr(ZE_TEST, "original files unmodified");
  }
```

the code basically builds a command string `cmd` and runs it with
`system()` function. `system()` is a C library function that:

> uses fork(2) to create a child process that executes
> the shell command specified in command using execl(3) as follows:
>
> ```
> execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command, (char *) NULL);
> ```
>
> system() returns after the command has been completed.

the command that gets executed by `check_zipfile()` is really:

```
/bin/sh -c "unzip -t -qq 'I've Been Everywhere (Today)/PDFs.zip'"
```

notice the two `'` around the filepath added with these lines:

```
strcat(cmd, "'");    /* accept space or $ in name */
strcat(cmd, zipname);
strcat(cmd, "'");
```

if `zipname` contains a `'` (as in your case) the shell command will be "broken"
because the two `'` added, do not "wrap" the full filepath anymore. if I try to
run the command, I get the same error reported by `zip`, that is a shell syntax
error:

```
$ sh -c "unzip -t -qq 'I've Been Everywhere (Today)/PDFs.zip'"
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
$
```

so the `-T` option runs a malformed shell command!

strangely enough, if your filepath doesn't include the directory path, i.e. you
pass just a *filename*, it can contain `'` without any issue e.g.:

```
$ zip -rmT "foo's bar.zip" PDFDirectory
updating: PDFDirectory/ (stored 0%)
updating: PDFDirectory/bar.pdf (stored 0%)
updating: PDFDirectory/baz.pdf (stored 0%)
updating: PDFDirectory/foo.pdf (stored 0%)
test of foo's bar.zip OK
$
```

I think it's because `zip` creates a temporary file for "zipping" and only at
the end renames it to the supplied name.

looking at the code for how this temporary file works, I was able to find
another workaround for the issue using the `-b` (`--temp-path`) option:

```
$ zip -rmT -b /tmp "I've Been Everywhere (Today)/PDFs.zip" PDFDirectory
  adding: PDFDirectory/ (stored 0%)
  adding: PDFDirectory/bar.pdf (stored 0%)
  adding: PDFDirectory/baz.pdf (stored 0%)
  adding: PDFDirectory/foo.pdf (stored 0%)
test of I've Been Everywhere (Today)/PDFs.zip OK
$ ls I\'ve\ Been\ Everywhere\ \(Today\)/
PDFs.zip
$
```

using `-b`, `zip` will execute the command:

```
/bin/sh -c "unzip -t -qq '/tmp/ziXXXXXX'"
```

for the `-T` option which is a well formed shell command and at the end, it will
rename `/tmp/ziXXXXXX` to `I've Been Everywhere (Today)/PDFs.zip`.